# Why can't I forward declare static member variables using extern?

Tags: c++, static

Why isn't this valid C++:

MyExample1A.cpp:

```
struct A;
extern int A::foo;

int main() {
    A::foo = 5;
}
```

MyExample1B.cpp:

```
struct A {
    static int foo;
};
int A::foo;
```

As far as I can tell, this shouldn't be that different from working with any other variable with static storage duration and external linkage. E.g.

MyExample2A.cpp:

```
extern int bar;

int main() {
    bar = 7;
}
```

MyExample2B.cpp:

```
int bar;
```

Is there a difference between `A::foo` and `bar` other than what the mangled symbol name becomes?

I understand that A is an incomplete type and so C++ forbids this, what I want to know is why? What is the reason for making this language design choice? Is there some technical limitation, would it make some code ambiguous, was it just a style choice, etc?

Comment: In the first code snippet the struct A is an incomplete type. It is unknown for the compiler what data members it has. So the compiler issues an error for this declaration extern int A::foo;

Comment: Although the dupe is about static member functions, the answer there concerns all static members.

Comment: Are you asking what the reason for making this language design choice are? If so I would suggest clarifying it. Otherwise the assumption will be that you are asking whether/what rules of the language prohibit it (as in the linked duplicate).